# perl on win2003 (strawberry perl) - how to get current bandwidth usage?

Tags: windows, perl, bandwidth

Title pretty much tells everything. Is it possible to get current bandwidth usage in windows2003 via a perl script (using strawberry perl) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rarely use Windows, and don't currently have access to a Windows machine, but you should be able to use WMI/WQL to get what you need.

This distribution provides a DBI interface to WMI:

https://metacpan.org/release/DBD-WMI

The correct query would be along the lines of

```
Select Name, currentbandwidth
  FROM Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface
```

[More about that class from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394293%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).